# A simple quiz with 3 buttons ANDROID

Tags: android, button

I'm trying a make a quiz with 3 choices/buttons, so when one button is clicked, it will move to the next question by changing the 3 buttons' texts and the textview (displays the question). For example, I have 3 questions. I used a for loop to loop all the questions but this strategy does not seem to work. Is there a better suggestion of how I should implement my codes?

```
for(int k=0; k<3;k++){
  t1.setText(Quizz[k].questionText);//textview displays the question
buttons[0].setText(Quizz[k].answers.get(0).getText());
  buttons[1].setText(Quizz[k].answers.get(1).getText());
    buttons[2].setText(Quizz[k].answers.get(2).getText());

//go through three values stored in three buttons
for(int run = 0;run<3;run++){
  if(Quizz[k].answers.get(run).getCorrect()==true){
buttons[k].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {

   public void onClick(View v)
   {

       //continue to next question
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You just clicked the correct button =)",
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

        }
        else {

            buttons[k].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {


                public void onClick(View v)
                {
               //continue to next question
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops that's not right)",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
            }
        //no matter if correct or wrong, go to the next question



    }
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: The loop just goes to the end as soon as the app is opened, displaying the last question.

Comment: So I want to do increment the loop only until user clicks something, But I don't know how this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only tell you how I would do this.. Not sure this will be compilable but will hopefully give you an idea. Uses three buttons in the xml layout linked with the onClick() method (i.e button1 linked to answered(1) using onClick() )

```
int currentquestion = 0;

public void updateQuestion() {

    t1.setText(Quizz[currentquestion].questionText);
    buttons[0].setText(Quizz[currentquestion].answers.get(0).getText());
    buttons[1].setText(Quizz[currentquestion].answers.get(1).getText());
    buttons[2].setText(Quizz[currentquestion].answers.get(2).getText());
}

public void answered(View clickedButton, int answer) {
    if (Quizz[currentquestion].answers.get(answer).getCorrect() ) {
        // code to celebrate
    } else {
        // other code
    }

    currentquestion++;
    updateQuestion();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the (View clickedButton）?　I'm not sure what the answered method do, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: I'll explain a bit more, though this is fairly simple android layout design stuff. Most android beginner tutorials will cover this stuff early on if you want more comprehensive explanations

After you have the buttons created (by xml in my example) you then link them to methods the program code. Keep in mind you have to attach the layout in the program code also.

When the button is clicked (assumed you've added the OnClick function) it calls the method linked. This method needs to take in (at least) the variable of the actual button. This would allow you to get information about it

Comment: so in this case, the "answered" method is receiving the button (which is required) but also an integer of either 0, 1 or 2 to help inform which button was pressed.

Using that information you can find out which button was pressed and do whatever depending on that

Answer (score 0):

if you simply doing loop in your main thread, it will executed right from the first code till the end, you will only see the result.

try to create method that display the question when it is called. and you simply listen to the event (e.g click)

the flowchart is like this:
display start button -> show question -> click -> process -> show question2 -> click -> process ..

Comment: Yes I put this in the MainActivity and in the onCreate method. Where should I put it then?

Comment: you don't need to create any loop.. just listen to the event.